# Problems with sdk and ndk in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can't build the project and use unity remote. What to do? Downloaded the latest 2020 LTS with a development package for android

[External Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohWch.png)

[Unity hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXNL3.png)

Comment: "Can't build" doesn't tell us anything about the issue you're having. Describe your process and result. Include any errors you're receiving.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I am not getting any errors. Just when building, he writes that he needs a SDK

Answer (score 0):

When installing a version from the Unity Hub, make sure you have selected the various android packages as you see in the image.

[image]

You have shown a link where you show that you did. If the procedure is the one I showed you above, you are not wrong.

Perhaps the problem may be related to Unity 2020.3.15 which in fact I do not find among the available downloads and which was released a few days ago. Maybe they caught some bugs (like maybe what you are showing), and took it out of the releases. Try downloading the 2020.3.14 version from the site (the one I use too), and see if the problem persists.

https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive